# How do I create a copy of a variable to assign a different value to it in Python 3.6?

Tags: python-3.x

I am reasonably new to python, using 3.6, and am a bit stuck. my program -

```
import time
asdm = input ('what operation is it? ')       #tell the program which operation
while True:                                   #list is in the program
    if asdm == 'idk':                         #if the answer of the question
        print('* = product of')               #is 'idk', list these options
        print('/ = quotient of')
        print('+ = sum of')
        print('- = subtract')
        print('** = to the power of')
        print('// = floored quotient of')
        print('% = remainder of')
        print('')
        time.sleep(1)
        asdm = old_asdm
    asdm = input('what operation is it? ')     #ask the same question
    if not 'idk':                              #if the answer is one of the listed
        break                                  #end the loop
time.sleep(3)
while True:
    print ('what are the variables?')
    a = input ('what is the value of a? ')      #value 'a'
    b = input ('what is the value of b? ')      #value 'b'
    if asdm == '*':                             #if multiplication
        print ('a * b')
        print (a * b)                           #print 'a*b' and the answer
    if asdm == '/':                             #if division
        print ('a / b')
        print (a / b)                           #print 'a/b' and the answer
    if asdm == '+':                             #if addition
        print ('a + b')
        print (a + b)                           #print 'a+b' and the answer
    if asdm == '-':                             #if subtraction
        print ('a - b')
        print (a - b)                           #print 'a-b' and the answer
    if asdm == '**':                            #if power
        print ('a ** b')
        print (a ** b)                          #print 'a**b' and the answer
    if asdm == '//':                            #is division with no remainder`
        print ('a // b')
        print (a // b)                          #print 'a//b' and the answer
    time.sleep(4)
    input('another equation? ')
    if 'no':
        break
time.sleep(3)                               #end
input ('Leave?')
```

- How do I make a copy of asdm to use that in place of the `idk` assigned `asdm`?
  I have everything else working right (presumably), but this little bit I don't understand.

Comment: Posting the error you get makes it easier for us to help you

Comment: Can you please try to reduce your code to a smaller version that shows the same problem? see https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not entirely sure what you want to achieve but i think this should work.

I put your input inside the first while loop. This way the asdm variable can simply be reused if it is not "idk" in the next part of your code (instead of asking it again). In your code you try to the statement `asdm = old_asdm` where old_asdm is not defined yet, which should error. also your check `if not 'idk'` does was not valid. You need to check asdm != 'idk'.
Finally after all the inputs come through you try to do mathematical operations with strings, so i casted the strings to numbers using float() on the inputs. The final another equation input conditional statement also contained the same error similar to the one above.

```
import time

while True:                                   #list is in the program
    asdm = input ('what operation is it? ')       
    if asdm == 'idk':                         #if the answer of the question
        print('* = product of')               #is 'idk', list these options
        print('/ = quotient of')
        print('+ = sum of')
        print('- = subtract')
        print('** = to the power of')
        print('// = floored quotient of')
        print('% = remainder of')
        print('')
        time.sleep(1)
    if asdm != 'idk'::                              #if the answer is one of the listed
        break                                  #end the loop
time.sleep(3)
while True:
    print ('what are the variables?')
    a = float(input('what is the value of a? '))      #value 'a'
    b = float(input('what is the value of b? '))      #value 'b'
    if asdm == '*':                             #if multiplication
        print ('a * b')
        print (a * b)                           #print 'a*b' and the answer
    if asdm == '/':                             #if division
        print ('a / b')
        print (a / b)                           #print 'a/b' and the answer
    if asdm == '+':                             #if addition
        print ('a + b')
        print (a + b)                           #print 'a+b' and the answer
    if asdm == '-':                             #if subtraction
        print ('a - b')
        print (a - b)                           #print 'a-b' and the answer
    if asdm == '**':                            #if power
        print ('a ** b')
        print (a ** b)                          #print 'a**b' and the answer
    if asdm == '//':                            #is division with no remainder`
        print ('a // b')
        print (a // b)                          #print 'a//b' and the answer
    time.sleep(4)
    another_equation = input('another equation? ')
    if another_equation == 'no':
        break
time.sleep(3)                               #end
input ('Leave?')
```

Comment: When I run the program, it keeps on thinking that the value of 'asdm' is 'idk', so I couldn't get out of the loop. The code works so much better. thank you so much. This is due today, it seems, so it'sw really helpful, thank you

Comment: did I just do your homework? o.O Hope you get an A then! ;)

Comment: you kind of did, but that was just the second hurdle. need to make a super complex for beginners code, and it's either this code, or a guess the number code.I don't think I can do much with the guess code, and I can't really do much more with the other code, for an arduino car, so it's this one that's left. I'm currently working on putting in a save so that at the end I can put in an input to ask if the user wants to do another equation, and it goes to the start point. I don't suppose you know how to do that, do you?

Comment: oh, and I got help from a kid in my class, Jordan. He's an absolute tech nerd, so python, c#, c+, etc. He's into it all. So if I make iasdm = None', then it resets asdm, and then there was the issue of the break. so I put in the question again, and then 'if asdm != 'idk': break', it works. I don't know why, but it didn't seem to copy from when I replaced my code with yours, so I assumed it would all be right (except the double colon)

Comment: "I'm currently working on putting in a save so that at the end I can put in an input to ask if the user wants to do another equation, and it goes to the start point. I don't suppose you know how to do that, do you?" I would use a while True loop, and the end with if input("Another equation? (yes/no") == 'no': break. I'm not really sure what you mean with the second comment.

Comment: `while True:
  restart = None
  rep += 1
  if rep >= 1:
    asdm = None
    asdm = input('what is the operation? ')
  print ('what are the variables?')
  a = None
  a = float(input('what is the value of a? '))
  b = None
  b = float(input('what is the value of b? '))
  if asdm == '*':
    print('a * b')
    print(a * b)`
       etc.
  `time.sleep(4)
  restart = input('Do you want another equation? ')
  if restart == 'no' or 'No' or 'NO':
    break`

Comment: It doesn't seem to want to do what I want it to do, and it seems to think that 'rep' isn't 0 so it asks twice what the operation is. That's a bit of a dodgy bit, but the problem is that the loop ends even if the response to `input('Do you want another equation? ')` is 'yes'. This is rather paining, since that's kind of a key point to the program now.

Comment: The problem has to do with your statement: if restart == 'no' or 'No' or 'NO': If you type restart == 'no' or 'No' or 'NO' in the python terminal you will see it always returns True, no matter what restart is. That's because it checks whether restart == 'no' first. Then it checks the "Truth value" of 'No' (which is always True since its a non-empty string. The same with the 'NO'. So what you want to do is the following: if restart == 'no' or restart == 'No' or restart == 'NO':. Or prettier: if restart in ['no', 'No', 'NO]:

Comment: Also can you accept my earlier answer since i solved your problems ;)

Comment: never mind that first part. It was because I was letting `rep += 1` and then `if rep >= 1:`...

Comment: yeah. I got 100%. Mr. B, the teacher, was going to give me 97, a 7/10 for complex coding, I think it was, but then he decided that I was that close and didn't want to dissappoint me I guess, and gave me 100

Comment: @DaleMack Hahaha nice! Thanks for letting me know, put a smile on my face.